# unable to add elements to thread safe locking queue of shared pointers

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, ipc, shared-ptr

I'm trying to create an inter thread message based communications using C++11 concurrency techniques.  Anthony William's book 'Concurrency in Action'  describes a thread safe locking queue which this implementation is based on.  The difference between the thread safe locking queue that is described in the book and the one I want to implement is firstly that I am using universal references to forward queue elements to the blocking queue, and secondly (and this is where things are going wrong) I need to be able to store a queue of std::shared_ptr pointers as the template types consist of a simple message class hierarchy with an abstract base class and sub-classes with the actual specialized messages.  I need to use shared pointers to avoid data slicing.

**EDIT**: I added a coliru demo to show my problem more clearly.
[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ac31a462fe27bb0a)

**EDIT 1**: more updates to the coliru live demo with additional compiler errors:
[Coliru Demo With Compiler Errors](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d27efc5cd5b5e985)

**EDIT 2**: Thanks to Alejandro I have a working solution [Working Coliru Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d04973a3cf6ba8a5)

To this end I changed Anthony William's implementation of the underlying message queue from:

```
std::queue<T> data_queue
```

to a

```
std::queue<std::shared_ptr<T>> data_queue
```

but then when I attempt to push message pointers on the queue via the universal reference perfect forwarding signature, I get all sorts of errors.

The way I would like to be able to add message on this queue is as follows:

```
UtlThreadSafeQueue<BaseMessageType>& mDataLoadSessionQ;
auto message = std::make_shared<DerivedType>(1,2,3);
mDataLoadSessionQ.push(BaseType);
```

> With the above code, the compiler complains indicating something along
>   the following lines  error C2664: 'void
>   UtlThreadSafeQueue::push(T &&)' : cannot convert
>   argument 1 from 'std::shared_ptr' to
>   'BaseMessageType &&' with T=BaseMessageType

I think I need some way to specialize pointer types but I am not sure.

My implementation is as follows:

```
/*
** code adapted from Anthony Williams's book C++ Concurrency in Action
** Pages 74-75.
**
*/

#ifndef _utlThreadSafeQueue_h_
#define _utlThreadSafeQueue_h_

// SYSTEM INCLUDES
#include <atomic>
#include <queue>
#include <limits>
#include <memory>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

// APPLICATION INCLUDES
// MACROS
#if defined (_WIN32) && (defined (max) || defined (min))
    // Windows uses min/max macros
    #undef min
    #undef max
#endif

// EXTERNAL FUNCTIONS
// EXTERNAL VARIABLES
// CONSTANTS
// STRUCTS

template<typename T>
class UtlThreadSafeQueue {
private:
    mutable std::mutex mut;
    std::queue<std::shared_ptr<T>> data_queue;
    std::condition_variable data_cond;
    std::size_t capacity;
    std::atomic<bool> shutdownFlag;
public:
    explicit UtlThreadSafeQueue(const size_t& rCapacity =
        std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max())
        : mut()
        , data_queue()
        , data_cond()
        , capacity(rCapacity)
        , shutdownFlag(false)
    {}

    UtlThreadSafeQueue(UtlThreadSafeQueue const& rhs) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(rhs.mut);
        data_queue = rhs.data_queue;
    }

    virtual ~UtlThreadSafeQueue() = default;

    // move aware push
    inline void push(T&& value) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mut);
        // only add the value on the stack if there is room
        data_cond.wait(lock,[this]{return (data_queue.size() < capacity) || shutdownFlag;});
        data_queue.emplace(std::forward<T>(value));
        data_cond.notify_one();
    }

    // wait for non empty lambda condition before returning value
    inline void wait_and_pop(T& rValue) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mut);
        data_cond.wait(lock,[this]{return !data_queue.empty();});
        // ideally should return an invalid value
        if (!shutdownFlag) {
            rValue = data_queue.front();
            data_queue.pop();
        }
    }

    // wait for non empty lambda condition before returning shared pointer to value
    inline std::shared_ptr<T> wait_and_pop() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mut);
        data_cond.wait(lock,[this]{return !data_queue.empty() || shutdownFlag;});
        if (shutdownFlag) {
            std::shared_ptr<T> res(std::make_shared<T>(data_queue.front()));
            data_queue.pop();
            return res;
        }
        return nullptr;
    }

    // return value in specified reference and flag indicating whether value
    // successfully returned or not
    inline bool try_pop(T& rValue) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mut);
        if (data_queue.empty()) {
            return false;
        }
        rValue = data_queue.front();
        data_queue.pop();
        return true;
    }

    // return shared pointer to value - which if set to nullptr,
    // indicates container was empty at the time of the call.
    inline std::shared_ptr<T> try_pop() {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mut);
        if (data_queue.empty()) {
            return std::shared_ptr<T>();
        }
        std::shared_ptr<T> res(std::make_shared<T>(data_queue.front()));
        data_queue.pop();
        return res;
    }
    // thread safe method to check if the queue is empty
    // note that if it is empty
    inline bool empty() const {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mut);
        return data_queue.empty();
    }

    // shutdown support - wake up potentially sleeping queues
    inline void shutdown() {
        shutdownFlag = true;
        data_cond.notify_all();
    }
};

#endif // _utlThreadSafeQueue_h_
```

Comment: Alejandro, the base type is any abstract base class and a derived class is just that - a class derived from the base, I don't think the details are particularly important as long as I can store them as a std::queue<std::shared_ptr<Base>> in the UtlThreadSafeQueue<T> - where T is Base in this case - it can be a simple struct if you wish

Comment: `mDataLoadSessionQ.push(BaseType);` What's `BaseType` here, and how, if at all, is it related to `message`? Anyway, `push` needs to take `shared_ptr<T>`, for the same reason that various flavors of `pop` return `shared_ptr<T>`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, that's what I've been trying to figure out!

Comment: added a live coliru demo to clarify - sorry I was vague before

Comment: The coliru demo certainly does clarify it. Your trying to call `push` with a `std::shared_ptr`, but `push` is expecting a `BaseMessage&&`. `shared_ptr` is not convertible to such a type

Comment: @IgorTandetnik - is there any way to still allow universal references - BTW I'm about to add another coliru edit and I am still having problems as you can see,  This time the compiler details are a lot more verbose

Comment: `is there any way to still allow universal references` To what end? What goal are you trying to achieve, that you feel would be advanced by using universal references?

Comment: @johnco3 , both links you've put up have been dead (albeit 1 of them fixed)

Comment: in `wait_and_pop()` you're trying to make a `shared_ptr<BaseMessage>` by constructing it with another `shared_ptr` via a call to `make_shared` . There are several things wrong with that. 1) If you're already storing `shared_ptr`s in `data_queue`, why are you constructing a `shared_ptr` from a previous one? 2) BaseMessage has no constructor taking `std::shared_ptr<BaseMessage>&`, so what did you expect  `std::make_shared<T>(data_queue.front())` to do?

Comment: @Alejandro - the links seem to be working (in the sense that they show code with compiler errors) for me - I just tested them now

Comment: Yes, I edited the question  to fix the links =)

Comment: @Alejandro - looks like I have the compilation issue fixed - I made a stupid programming error in migrating my previously working UtlThreadSafeQueue<T> which used a std::queue<T> to a std::queue<std::shared_ptr<T>> - no need for additional make_shared calls as the parameter is already in pointer form.  I'm making additional changes to coliru example in attempt to flush out remaining bugs thanks to your input

Comment: @Alejandro - why don't you post an answer so I can give you credit - looks like I have something working here per my last edit

Comment: @johnco3 , just did. don't know if it answers your question fully, but its way more than I could fit into these comment boxes :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following the extended discussion in the comments, and as per the Coliru links, I think I understand what you were originally attempting to do, and I'd also like to make some suggestions for your data structure.

- You mentioned that your `push()` function is move aware. Excellent! But, be careful.

  If you look at how you defined your `push` function,

  ```
  inline void push(T&& value)
  ```

  there's a few things I'd like to point out here. The first is that this will only bind to r-value references and *not* universal references (or, [forwarding references](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4164.pdf) , as they will soon be called ). Your use of `std::forward` within `push` is the inappropriate thing to do (albeit technically correct). The reason is that the type `T` will have already been deduced at the class level ( when you instantiate a `UtlThreadSafeQueue`). To get perfect-forwarding semantics, you would need a `push` like the following:

  ```
  template<typename U>
  inline void push(U&& value) { ... }
  ```

  This version of `push` accepts any type of reference, as you would expect. However, it's use would be to *forward* along any arguments to an appropriate constructor/function/etc. Since you wish to maintain an internal `std::queue<std::shared_ptr<BaseMessage>>` , you can have a `push` that accepts a reference (lvalue or rvalue) to a derived type of `BaseMessage`, and emplace a `std::shared_ptr<DerivedType>` into the queue. This would establish a pointer-to-base relationship (`std::shared_ptr<BaseMessage> base_ptr = derived_ptr`, where `derived_ptr` is of type `std::shared_ptr<DerivedMessage>`). This can be accomplished with the following:

  ```
  template<typename U>
  inline
  std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<T,std::decay_t<U>>::value> push(U&& value)   
  {

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mut);
    // only add the value on the stack if there is room
    data_cond.wait(lock,[this]{return (data_queue.size() < capacity) || shutdownFlag;});
    data_queue.emplace(std::make_shared<std::decay_t<U>> (std::forward<U>(value)));
    data_cond.notify_one();
  }
  ```

  The use of `std::enable_if_t` makes sure that only types that are derived    from `BaseMessage` are passed in to the `push` function. The emplacement into the queue of `std::make_shared<std::decay_t<U>> (std::forward<U>(value))` will call the 9th constructor of `std::shared_ptr` (as listed [Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr) ).

  The great thing about this, is that it will allow you and your users to write code like this:

  ```
  UtlThreadSafeQueue<BaseMessage> dataLoadSessionQ(10);
  StringMessage sm("Hi there!");
  IntegerMessage im(4242);
  dataLoadSessionQ.push(sm);
  dataLoadSessionQ.push(im);
  ```

  And it would behave as expected. Each Message is passed in by lvalue-ref and a `shared_ptr` is made by calling the copy-ctor of the derived type.
- You're exposing a `push` interface that accepts not just a `std::shared_ptr`, but a `std::shared_ptr&&` which has some subtleties.

  At first glance, it may seem as if I wouldn't be able to do this ( borrowing the `StringMessage` and `BaseMessage` types from your Coliru links):

  ```
    UtlThreadSafeQueue<BaseMessage> dataLoadSessionQ;
    auto my_message = std::make_shared<StringMessage>("Another message!");
    dataLoadSessionQ.push(my_message);
  ```

  Despite the fact that `push` is defined to take an r-value reference to a `shared_ptr`, this code compiles by passing it `my_message` (which is not an r-value reference!). And the reason was not immediately clear to me at first. But, as it turns out, similar to `static_cast`, there's a `static_pointer_cast` defined for `shared_ptr` which looks like the following ( borrowed from [Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast) ):

  ```
  template< class T, class U > 
  std::shared_ptr<T> static_pointer_cast( const std::shared_ptr<U>& r );
  ```

  It will perform a conversion from a `shared_ptr<U>` to a `shared_ptr<T>` if such a conversion succeeds. Because your Coliru example uses a `std::queue<std::shared_ptr<BaseMessage>>` internally, and you're trying to push a `shared_ptr<StringMessage>`, the *implicit* conversion to `shared_ptr<BaseMessage>` succeeds since `StringMessage` inherits from `BaseMessage`. The conversion returns an alias-constructed`std::shared_ptr<BaseMessage>`, which will happily bind to the rvalue-reference.

  Notice that if you instead try this:

  ```
  UtlThreadSafeQueue<BaseMessage> dataLoadSessionQ;
  auto generic_message = std::make_shared<BaseMessage>(); 
  dataLoadSessionQ.push(generic_message);
  ```

  You get the compiler error we ( or maybe it was just me) were expecting initially

> error: cannot bind 'std::shared_ptr' lvalue to 'std::shared_ptr&&'
>        dataLoadSessionQ.push(generic_message);

I honestly can't find a good reason from either a performance or aesthetic aspect to have to pass in a `shared_ptr<Derived>` to a `UtlThreadSafeQueue<Base>`. I expect to be able to pass in ***both*** a temporary `Derived` and an lvalue, and not fret with the internals of the queue too much.
      You can also capitalize in the `wait_and_pop()`/`try_pop()` that return `shared_ptr`s by `std::move`ing the value from `data_queue.front()` (since it was going to be destructed anyways in the next call to `data_queue.pop()`)

In your `UtlThreadSafeQueue` constructor, I would also consider changing the `const std::size_t&` to just a by-value `std::size_t` and likewise for the (example) `IntegerMessage` type.

With this in mind, I would appreciate any feedback to the changes I highlighted above - I just quite frankly couldn't grok your goal / implementation until much later when you posted more examples and kept editing the question.

Comment: I was able to use the code u wrote above, however I was wondering if you would have a look a this updated coliru and explain why I cannot forward shared_ptr's to the push method.  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6d695bf42e72b91c  I'm very new to meta programming stuff, and I figured you might know have it figured, I have a lot of code that already has these shared_ptr objects already constructed outside the UtlThreadSafeQueue<T> and although I can get them to work by prefixing them with a *T and using your method, I would prefer to perfect forward the overload shared_ptr<U>

Comment: Hey @johnco3, the reason you can't push a `std::shared_ptr` to the `push` I wrote is because of the `enable_if_t` which only accepts arguments that are derived from `BaseMessage` - `shared_ptr` obviously doesn't derive from it. I understand you may have some design choices to use `shared_ptr`s, so try [this demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bb902579cc5b4a56) out.

Comment: I'm surprised that the class requires both a const and non const (universal ref) variant.  I modified it to have a single method and changed the std::move to std::forward in what I thought was the universal reference push method that takes a (std::shared_ptr<U>&& ptr) parameter - I thought that would indicate that it is a universal reference which is why I changed the move to std::forward<U> however the compiler had a fit! http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fca9671bf98ab9f3 any chance you could take a look?  Can you recommend a good book on this meta stuff, the online resources have been weak

Comment: @johnco3 , I honestly think you are confused about universal (forwarding) references. Scott Meyers has an excellent [talk about Universal References in C++11](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Scott-Meyers-Universal-References-in-Cpp11) and I think you would benefit greatly from it. What you wrote in your `push` is *not* a forwarding reference, its *strictly* an rvalue-reference (despite there being a `template<typename U>`). I would highly recommend watching Scott's talk - it may answer your question.

Comment: I viewed that video a few days ago, but it was not too clear about when a simple type&& universal reference args can be perfect forwarded when the arg becomes a pointer - he has another talk that covers that - but the audio is corrupted right at the point he discusses this issue. Its right at the end of https://www.facebook.com/Engineering/videos/10151094464083109/  in an area entitled "Specializing forwarding templates" Thanks for being so patient with a relative newbie

Comment: Since I only have a few hundred characters in this comment box, can we [continue this in this chat room?](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/79602/unable-to-add-elements-to-thread-safe-locking-queue-of-shared-pointers-discussi)